# "SFTP Append" is throwing java.io.IOException: Can't create the file without the Truncate flag even after changing duplicate handling to append

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft

Project runtime: Version: 3.9.1 Build: a179eae3

We have a scenario where we have to "APPEND" files using SFTP connector.

Changed SFTP > file tab > "duplicate handling" property to "append"

But still while testing it Mule is throwing following error.

java.io.IOException: File already exists. Can't create file without Truncate flag

Is mule 3.9 supporting Append for SFTP?

Comment: if you flip it to overwrite, do you get a similar error?

Comment: no. Overwrite works fine.